# Upgrading 16.04 to 16.04.1

Tags: upgrade

I can't find any documentation on upgrading 16.04 to 16.04.1.  I'm assuming having all the package updates does it, but Details is still reporting 16.04 and there is still a 'developer options' tab in Software & Updates, implying I'm still in some experimental release.

Comment: And do not enable `proposed` in the "Developer options". It will install unstable packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `cat /etc/lsb-release` and you will see that you already have 16.04.1.

If not, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

In System Settings GUI you see the major release number.

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade` says no upgrade available and `cat /etc/lsb-release` still shows `16.04`

Comment: same issue here.