# My computer is not receiving the 16.04.1 update

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, lts, versions

I've [read recently](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/ubuntu-16-04-1-lts-released-upgrade) that the 16.04.1 update was made public last week. There it says that users of 16.04 should only run the usual system update to receive this upgrade. However I'm not receiving this update at all. I tried with GUI Software Updater as well as Terminal commands `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, to no avail. I've changed the update server from `Main` to `US` and back to `Main` again, no effect. I've changed settings from `Any new version` to `LTS only` and back to `Any new version` again, still nothing.

I would like to know, if I'm not receiving the upgrade, what could be the reason for that, and also how can I make 100% sure that I'm running 16.04 and not 16.04.1? In System Details I can see it says `Ubuntu 16.04`, does that mean that it's definitely not `.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue too. Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801677/upgrading-16-04-to-16-04-1):

You can see what version you have by running:

```
lsb_release -a
```

And you can upgrade by running (`apt` instead of `apt-get`):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Let me know how it works?

And, yes, you would see `16.04.1` instead of `16.04`. Here is a screenshot of my output:

[image: Output from lsb_release -a]